# How to display sqlite particular column in android activity?

Tags: android, sqlite

In using select * from table name it display all the columns in a table of sqlite.In case of *(Astriek) i replace a some column names,I can't able to fetch a data's. It works on sqlite but not work in android coding part.Please rectify those things.If using Select * from table name it works,instead of that if we specify some column name it won't display.

```
     protected void adddata1() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //tr1.removeAllViewsInLayout();


                    Database db=new Database(Boreport.this);
                    SQLiteDatabase sb=db.getReadableDatabase();

     Cursor cus=sb.rawQuery("select boatname,amount from Auction",null);// The problem Line

                        cus.moveToFirst();

                         for(int i=0;i<cus.getCount();i++)
                             {

                             if(cus.getString(0).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(boatno.getText().toString()))
                             {

                    bn.setText(cus.getString(1));

                    amount.setText(cus.getString(2));

                             }
cus.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: If you select only **1** column (boatname) and then try to retrieve **3** columns (getString(0), getString(1) and getString(2))... How is it expected to work?!

Comment: ya right..but how can i check the if condition,if it's * only i have to check.otherwise i can't.

Comment: **1** Nobody can predict the **order** in which the columns are returned when you query `*`. So referring them **by index** is potentially catastrophic. **2** You **must** include in your query **all** the fields you want to get back. Including those ones on which you perform checks.

Comment: Thank you so much Der Golem....U made my day..silly thing took my whole day....thank uuuuuuuuuu

Answer (score -1):

You can use query() method for your task

Check this :

```
 Cursor cus=sb.query("Auction", new String[] {"boatname","amount"}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not much useful.